# Creating a Searchable spinner that Loads from Fire Base

Tags: android, performance, firebase, spinner, searchable

I am trying to create a searchable spinner that loads the counties information from firebase.  I am new at android development and I based what I did on various videos on youtube and a stack overflow post.  Heres what I have so far in my activity:

```
public class Preferences extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchableSpinner spcounties;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    List<String> countyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

        spcounties = (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spcounties);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String county = ds.child("County").getValue(String.class);
                    countyList.add(county);
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countyList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spcounties.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Preferences.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My DB is structured like so:
[image]

Right now my app crashes when the searchable spinner is clicked on.

Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jws.documentmarketplace, PID: 17515
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:454)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2405)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1417)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1323)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6821)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25185)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6821)
        at android.widget.Fra
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo Added stacktrace looks like a null exception error but I don't understand how since the data comes from the DB and there are no null entries.

Comment: I added a null exception check for `ds.child("County").getValue(String.class)`.  I found that that call is not grabbing any data from the db.  My guess is I don't have the DB call set up properly to get the data.  Anybody know the proper way to set up a firebase call with my database configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line and it worked.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Counties/");
```